# Create file in Java library that can be read by a consuming application

Tags: java

I'm creating a Java sdk which I ultimately want a file called `version` to contain a string of the current version of the sdk.

I want to read this file and pass it along in underlying API calls I make within the sdk.

Currently this file is located in `src/main/resources/version` and simply contains `0.1.0`.

I have this method which reads the file and returns the version.

```java
private static String getVersion() {
        URL versionFile = ConfigurationUtils.class.getResource("version");
        Path path = Paths.get(String.valueOf(versionFile));
        String version = null;
        try {
            version = Files.readAllLines(path).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // The project should never build without if this happens so therefore just print a stacktrace
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return version;
    }
```

In another project where I'm trying to use this sdk, i'm getting a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: null` on this line

[image]

I can see that the file actually does exist in my dependencies though [image]

Any idea what i'm missing here?

** Update **

When trying the suggestion from the possible duplicate, my sdk won't even compile b/c it's getting a null pointer exception on this line when running my tests.

[image]

`src/main/resources/version` surely exists [image]

Comment: No it doesn't. I changed the code in `getVersion` to 

```try (InputStream in = ConfigurationUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("version");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
            version = reader.readLine();
```
and my sdk project won't build. A version file keeps appearing in `src/main/java/org/catalytic/sdk/version` when I run my tests.

Comment: For what it's worth, I bet it's faster to auto-generate a Version class with a static method that returns the version. It accomplishes the same thing, will take you a few minutes, be smaller and cleaner, and significantly faster at runtime.

Comment: Auto generate it from what? when would it be auto generated?

Comment: @Catfish When your project doesn't get build you have to check for compile errors. Keep in mind that `Files.readAllLines()` read from a file, but the `version` entry is inside a `jar`. Please edit your question to include the source code and error messages you get, when you try to read the file as mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: @Progman I've updated my question with the latest attempt from the possible duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @Catfish Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Also add to your question how you execute your "SDK", how you built your `jar` file and how you set your classpath when running your java application.

Comment: You should use `"/version"`, not `"version"`, and you should not try to convert to a path. Instead, use `getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the resource from the Jar because you're trying to read it as a file in which it is not. Instead, what you should be doing is reading all of the lines of the InputStream using a BufferedReader.

```java
    private static String getVersion() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(ConfigurationUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("version")))) {
            return reader.lines()
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was missing `getClassLoader()`. So `ConfigurationUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("version");` should be `ConfigurationUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version");`